# scroll to anchor without jquery or smoothscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What can I do to write a plain javascript scroll to anchor item?

There is a plugin smoothscroll or Jquery but I don't wanna use this. I will write this in plain Javascript.

```
<a href="#contact">Click here to jump to Some Heading</a>
<div id="space" class="space"></div>
<div id="contact" class="contact"></div>
<a href="#space">Click here to jump to Some Heading</a>
```

Comment: Do you want an animation or just the scrolling?

Comment: have you tried anything ?